# Session timeout warnings in popups?

Tags: javascript, session, timer, popup

In my parent window I am setting a time-out function call once the user logs in using that alerts the user of a disconnection after 10 minutes.

```
var timer = setTimeOut(function(){ alert("Your session will expire soon."); }, 60 * 10 * 1000)
```

It gets extended if an Ajax call is made.

```
var reset = () => (clearTimeOut(timer); timer = setTimeOut(...))
```

How can I extend this feature into the popup windows? `setTimeOut` is only initialized in the parent so is it possible to bring the alerts into all the child windows as well? Also, I hope its just fine to call the `reset` function of my parent window using `window.opener.reset`? What is the preferred approach?

Or is it like modal or tabbed windows are preferred over popups to handle all these scenarios better?

Comment: Are you able to access parent method in `child-window` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I am able to access like `window.opener.reset`